# How to modify divs using data from JSONs

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am very new to JavaScript and I recently got an assignment to display several countries and some information about them on HTML using JSONs.
As I am still a beginner, i would like to know how to do it using .map and no .append or $.

```
<div class="country">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="area"></div>
    <div class="continent"></div>
  </div>
```

```
let countries = [
  { name: "Russia",
    description: "russia description",
    area: "17,098,246 km2",
    image: "./flags/Russia.png",
    continent: "Europe",
  },

  { name: "China",
    description: "china description",
    area: "9,596,961 km2",
    image: "./flags/China.png",
    continent: "Asia",
  },

  { name: "India",
    description: "india description",
    area: "3,287,263 km2",
    image: "./flags/India.png",
    continent: "Asia",
  },
  
  { name: "United States",
    description: "usa description",
    area: "9,833,520 km2",
    image: "./flags/USA.png",
    continent: "North America.",
  },
];
```

Comment: do you have the html already on the site or is it the template of what you have to display?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. People might be willing to help with homework but you need to attempt it yourself first and show your work. I'd suggest asking your professor/teacher for help instead.

Comment: The html itself is not a problem as i'm going to modify it after, what i'm looking for is how to be able to add what I want from the jsons to each div

Comment: Loop over all countries. For each country create a div. Append your html with your new divs. As @HazardousGlitch mentioned, this is very basic question yet you don't give any code which means you have long way to go. Either ask your teacher or do more research first. There is plenty on the topic already - just look into forEach/map loop and how to append html.

Comment: quickest way to do it will be to use template literals to interpolate html strings, using map to generate the strings to join together

Comment: you don't need map method for this, map will take an array, do something, and create a new one, if you want to use ecma6 features you need foreach lambda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is a simple way to do it, we are using a foreach iterator to cycle the array of objects you have (countries), than for each element (country) we will create the html elements and append them directly to body in this case, i left some original formating so you can understand better.
ps. using .map here makes no sence, since you dont need to mutate any information

```
countries.forEach(country => {
  document.body.innerHTML += 
  '<div class="country">' +
    '<div class="name">' + country.name + '</div>' +
    '<img src="' + country.image + '" alt="">' +
    '<div class="description">' + country.description + '</div>' + 
    '<div class="area">' + country.area + '</div>' +
    '<div class="continent">' + country.continent + '</div>' +
  '</div>'
});
```